# Extracting OMS custom fields via Azure Automation

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-log-analytics

I am authoring a custom deployment script for an OMS "solution". I need to extract custom fields from a particular field in LogAnalytics but I would like to define these in the ARM template so that when deployed, a dashboard reporting on these custom fields is available in the workspace for the user. I can't really locate arm deployment capability that can do the custom field definitions. Has anyone come across with anything that solved this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to configuring custom field extraction via an ARM template?